# Following the Django Tutorial - but saying 404 not found

Tags: python, django

I am on the first Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/), and I am just nearing the end of the first page. However when I go to localhost:8000/polls, is says 404 this page is not found. It was working fine until I added the code to the python files at the bottom of the page as it tells you to. I have included screenshots of all the code I have typed so far and the error message, and I was wondering whether anyone had any idea about what was wrong.

Thanks,
MIlo

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: What is in polls/urls.py?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of tracebacks and code, use the code formatting tool in the editor to add them there.

Comment: Dear Withnail - I am very sorry - I did not realise! Someone else has since revised it and I have agreed, so I hope it is all fine now. Thanks, Milo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `mysite/mysite/urls.py` that should include `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),`. Your screenshot shows that you have put this in the `mysite/polls/urls.py` instead.

The `mysite/polls/urls.py` should contain `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`.

Compare your `urls.py` files to those in the [writing your first view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view) section, and make sure they match *exactly*.

Comment: This was exactly the problem: I did everything you said and realised that I had forgot to import include() in mysite\urls.py

Answer (score 2):

The fact that django says it only tried:

```
1. ^admin/
```

Suggests that you either haven't saved the file after adding the `polls/` url, or you are not using the file you thought you were. To test, change the `admin/` url to e.g. `admin2/`, and then restart the server and navigate to `polls/` again. If you get the error message again, does it say `admin/` or `admin2/`?